# Generating all realized and unrealized trades using sql?

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

### PROBLEM:

**Given some positions in different financial securities, I would like to apply trades to them up to a given date. In doing so I would like to keep track which trades closed the position and opened a new one. The position is `CLOSED` when the Position Quantity becomes 0 after a trade is applied. A position is considered `OPENED` when the Position Quantity changes from 0 to something.**

---

### SETUP: **[SQL DEMO SOURCE](http://rextester.com/NICL94304)**

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tPosition 
(
    SecNum INT,
    Position INT
)

CREATE TABLE tTrade
(
    TradeID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TradeDate DATETIME,
    SecNum INT,
    Quantity INT
)
```

And some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO tPosition (SecNum, Position) 
SELECT 1, 100
UNION
SELECT 2, 200
UNION
SELECT 3, -300

INSERT INTO tTrade (TradeID, TradeDate, SecNum, Quantity)
SELECT 1, '1/1/2016', 1, -50
UNION
SELECT 2, '1/2/2016', 1, -50
UNION
SELECT 3, '1/3/2016', 1, -50
UNION
SELECT 4, '1/4/2016', 1, 50
UNION
SELECT 6, '1/5/2016', 3, 200
UNION
SELECT 7, '1/5/2016', 3, 200;
```

---

### SAMPLE SCENARIOS/CASES: **[SQL DEMO SOURCE](http://rextester.com/NICL94304)**

Without any trades my result would be (i.e. exactly the position table with 2 extra fields which will be useful later):

```
SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,     100,       NULL,           NULL
    2,     200,       NULL,           NULL
    3,     -300,      NULL,           NULL
```

---

So let's say I apply trades to the positions up to and including `1/1/2016`. This trade with `TradeID`:1, will affect the position for `securityID`: 1 as 100+(-50)=50 so my result should be:

```
SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,     50,       NULL,         NULL
    2,     200,      NULL,         NULL
    3,     -300,     NULL,         NULL
```

The `OpenedByTradeID` and `ClosedTradeID` are still `NULL` because the position hasn't crossed 0 yet.

---

If I apply trades up to and including `1/2/2016` I should get:

```
 SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,      0,       NULL,             2
    2,     200,      NULL,             NULL
    3,     -300,     NULL,             NULL
```

Notice that the position has become 0 so we record the `ClosedByTradeID` with the `tradeID` that closed this position.

---

Up to and including `1/3/2016` I should get:

```
 SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,      0,       NULL,             2
    1,     -50,       3,               NULL
    2,     200,      NULL,             NULL
    3,     -300,     NULL,             NULL
```

Notice that a new position was opened in `securityID`:1 by the latest `tradeID`:3 so we mark the `OpenedByTradeID` column with `TradeID`:3

---

Up to and including `1/4/2016` I should get:

```
 SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,      0,       NULL,              2
    1,      0,       3,                 4
    2,     200,      NULL,              NULL
    3,     -300,     NULL,              NULL
```

Notice that the position has become 0 so we record the `ClosedByTradeID` with the `tradeID` that closed this position -- `TradeID`:4

---

Up to and including `1/5/2016` is an **edge case**. There are 2 things happening here: *the application of the trade crosses the 0 mark so a new position needs to be formed AND 2 trades happen on the same day*.

Applying:

- `tradeID`:6 for `securityID`:3 would adjust the position to -100 (-300 + 200 = -100).
- Then we need to apply `tradeID`:7 but that would cross 0 (-100 + 200 = 100 crossing from neg -> pos) so we need to apply the part before crossing 0 to close the position and then start a new position with the remaining amount.
- Part of `tradeID`:7 [100] would adjust the position to 0 (-100 + 100 = 0) and close it (would be noted in `ClosedByTradeID` column) and then part of `tradeID`:7 [the remaining 100] would adjust the position to 100 (0 + 100 = 100) [would also get noted in `OpenedByTradeID` column].

Therefore, I should get:

```
 SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID
    1,      0,       NULL,              2
    1,      0,       3,                 4
    2,     200,      NULL,              NULL
    3,      0,       NULL,              7
    3,     100,       7,                NULL
```

---

This sounds like an islands problem but I just can't seem to figure out how to write this one.

Comment: `Without any trades my result would be (i.e. exactly the position table):` position table doesnt have `OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yes, those fields are in the result but not in the data table and they are null in the beginning. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: nahh my fault didnt read all. Ok I got until the part where you close by 0, what happen when go negative `-50` ? is open again?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - a new position opens up when you cross 0 and go negative for example and the trade that opened the new position is recorded in the OpenedByTradeID

Comment: Ok so if you go from `-50` to `0` then is close again? and if go up/down from 0 is open?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yes, exactly

Comment: I include a sql demo, you should include a large list of trades.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- Thank you for the sql demo. That's very helpful. I didn't want to confuse people by including too many trades but feel free

Comment: You should do It, For my experience when I solve problem with too few data later  OP start adding hiding constrains.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- added more trades

Comment: Your should look into recursive query. Or just use a cursor in a storprocedure. Because you are creating new rows. Have you try anything?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I tried to attack this as an islands and gaps problem but didn't really get anywhere. I haven't tried a cursor or while loop yet. Was hoping I wouldn't have to go down that route.

Comment: This is solvable without looping or using a cursor, it's just... A little complicated. I might try to write a solution.

Comment: Heh. Had a working solution to this then saw the comment about the possibility of a trade going from negative->positive in a single transaction... This is why you should probably include sample data that encompasses all the things you want to solve.

Comment: Here's an example of how you could do this: http://rextester.com/FLD9140 but the execution time is relatively slow. If you're dealing with a rather large result set, it might be inefficient.

Comment: @ZLK dont know why you didnt post as answer, and is very complicated so maybe some comments will help. The link show position 0 for the first 4 rows,

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, it's meant to show 0 for the first 4 rows. I added sample data to show how it would work with multiple opens / closes.

Comment: This is my prettiest question in SO

Comment: well after a slow start end well ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - thank you for all your help. It was an interesting problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it to work using the `WHILE` loop approach. Maybe there is a more efficient way but I think this works...

```
DECLARE @result TABLE
(
    SecNum INT,
    Position INT,
    OpenedByTradeID INT,
    ClosedByTradeID INT
)

INSERT INTO @result(SecNum, Position)
SELECT SecNum, Position
FROM dbo.tPosition

SELECT *
FROM @result
ORDER BY SecNum

DECLARE @CurTradeID INT
SELECT @CurTradeID = MIN(TradeID) FROM dbo.tTrade
WHILE(@CurTradeID IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @TradeQty INT, @TradeSecNum INT
     SELECT @TradeQty = Quantity, @TradeSecNum = SecNum FROM dbo.tTrade WHERE TradeID = @CurTradeID

     DECLARE @OldPos INT = (SELECT Position FROM @result WHERE ClosedByTradeID IS NULL AND SecNum = @TradeSecNum)

     -- IF THERE IS NO POSITION
     IF (@OldPos IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @result(SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID)
            SELECT @TradeSecNum, @TradeQty, @CurTradeID, NULL
        END

    -- IF THIS TRADE CLOSES THE POSITION
     ELSE IF (@OldPos + @TradeQty = 0) 
         BEGIN
            UPDATE @result 
            SET ClosedByTradeID = @CurTradeID, Position = Position + @TradeQty
            WHERE SecNum = @TradeSecNum AND ClosedByTradeID IS NULL
         END

     -- IF THIS TRADE MAKES THE POSITION CROSS THROUGH 0 i.e. IF TRADE MAKES POSITION CHANGE SIGN
     ELSE IF (SIGN(@OldPos + @TradeQty) <> SIGN(@OldPos))
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @RemainingAmt INT = @TradeQty + @OldPos

            UPDATE @result
            SET ClosedByTradeID = @CurTradeID, Position = 0
            WHERE SecNum = @TradeSecNum AND ClosedByTradeID IS NULL

            INSERT INTO @result(SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID)
            SELECT @TradeSecNum, @RemainingAmt, @CurTradeID, NULL
        END

    -- JUST UPDATE THE ACTIVE POSITION
     ELSE        
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @result 
            SET Position = Position + @TradeQty
            WHERE SecNum = @TradeSecNum AND ClosedByTradeID IS NULL
        END

    SELECT @CurTradeID = MIN(TradeID) FROM dbo.tTrade WHERE TradeID > @CurTradeID
END

SELECT *
FROM @result
ORDER BY SecNum
```

P.S.: I figured that I can make a temp table with the trades that I need before-hand and I can use that table instead of tTrade in my query above so I don't have to keep dealing with selecting the trades up to a particular date.

Comment: Told you a loop was easier. Consider using a cursor instead  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Comment: our DBA is ok with loops but not happy about cursors

Comment: Maybe you should check why is that? Because doesnt make sense do 100 request of 1 row, instead of a single request  of 100 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial work using recursive. I couldnt finish, but maybe others can have ideas.

I start working with only `SecNum = 1`

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/GAVDJ80305)

```
WITH DirectReports (SecNum, Position, OpenedByTradeID, ClosedByTradeID, level_id, TradeID)
AS (
    SELECT SecNum, Position, NULL as OpenedByTradeID, NULL as ClosedByTradeID, 1, null as TradeID
    FROM tPosition
    WHERE SecNum = 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.SecNum, 
           Position + Quantity as Position, 
           CASE WHEN Position = 0 and Position + Quantity <> 0 
                THEN T.TradeID
                ELSE NULL
           END as OpenedByTradeID,
           CASE WHEN Position <> 0 and Position + Quantity = 0 
                THEN T.TradeID
                ELSE NULL
           END as ClosedByTradeID,
           level_id + 1 as level_id,
           T.TradeID

    FROM DirectReports D
    JOIN (SELECT  *,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by SecNum ORDER BY TradeDate) as rn
          FROM tTrade                              
         ) T
      ON D.SecNum = T.SecNum     
     AND D.level_id = T.rn
)   
SELECT *
FROM DirectReports
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: In `level_id`: 5 the openedByTradeID value got lost, it should have been carried from `level_id`: 4 but I think otherwise this looks close...

Comment: Yes, I think have to include `LAG` in the `CASE ... ELSE` But not sure how will go. Help is apreciated.

Comment: The only thing you need to watch out here is that if you have a position of let's say 100 at some `level_id` and the trade is -200. Then you need to close the position of 100 and open a new position of -100 (100+(-100) = 0 and 0+(-100) = -100) because you will be crossing 0 when you apply that trade

Comment: What I told you about small sample, constrain start appearing :( Please update the question to include that case and show the desire output

Comment: Sorry, I tried to show that case also in the sample, I had added to the test cases per your earlier suggestion (TradeID: 6 & 7)

Comment: maybe it might be easier to break up that special case where it goes from negative -> positve or vice versa into 2 trades in some sort of a pre-processing step and then it might be easier to deal with it in the actual code.

Comment: I need the desire output.

Comment: what about ZLK answer?

Comment: done. See updated question. ZLK's answer gives me an error when I try to run it.