# How to create a table of realized trades and unrealized trades from trade data in R

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

So I've seen a `loop` solution to this from a similar question in `SQL` ([Generating all realized and unrealized trades using sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920379/generating-all-realized-and-unrealized-trades-using-sql))

I know how to go about solving this using a loop (you pretty much brute force the way one would logically calculate FIFO accounting of realized trades). I am interested in trying to find a vectorized solution if possible in R.

Let's say my data is in this form:

```
structure(list(Symbol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AAPL", class = "factor"), 
    TradeDate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-06-27", class = "factor"), 
    Date.Time = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2018-06-27;103743", 
    "2018-06-27;131314", "2018-06-27;132000", "2018-06-27;153317"
    ), class = "factor"), OrderTime = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L), .Label = c("2018-06-27;102850", "2018-06-27;130954", 
    "2018-06-27;132000", "2018-06-27;153018"), class = "factor"), 
    Buy.Sell = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("BUY", 
    "SELL"), class = "factor"), Quantity = c(539L, 8L, 100L, 
    -200L, -447L), Price = c(185, 184.4, 184.3969, 185.3, 185.3
    ), Proceeds = c(-99715, -1475.2, -18439.69, 37060, 82829.1
    ), Commission = c(-2.695, -1, 0, -1.50558, -3.3649713)), .Names = c("Symbol", 
"TradeDate", "Date.Time", "OrderTime", "Buy.Sell", "Quantity", 
"Price", "Proceeds", "Commission"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x03f524a0>)

   Symbol  TradeDate         Date.Time         OrderTime Buy.Sell Quantity    Price  Proceeds Commission
1:   AAPL 2018-06-27 2018-06-27;131314 2018-06-27;130954      BUY      539 185.0000 -99715.00  -2.695000
2:   AAPL 2018-06-27 2018-06-27;132000 2018-06-27;132000      BUY        8 184.4000  -1475.20  -1.000000
3:   AAPL 2018-06-27 2018-06-27;132000 2018-06-27;132000      BUY      100 184.3969 -18439.69   0.000000
4:   AAPL 2018-06-27 2018-06-27;153317 2018-06-27;153018     SELL     -200 185.3000  37060.00  -1.505580
5:   AAPL 2018-06-27 2018-06-27;153317 2018-06-27;153018     SELL     -447 185.3000  82829.10  -3.364971
```

The result I would like would look something like this:

```
   Symbol Buy.Sell Quantity    Price  Proceeds Commission             BUYTIME SellPrice            SELLTIME PROFIT
1:   AAPL      BUY      539 185.0000 -99715.00     -2.695 2018-06-27 13:20:00     185.3 2018-06-27 15:33:17 161.70
2:   AAPL      BUY        8 184.4000  -1475.20     -1.000 2018-06-27 13:20:00     185.3 2018-06-27 15:33:17   7.20
3:   AAPL      BUY      100 184.3969 -18439.69      0.000 2018-06-27 10:37:43     185.3 2018-06-27 15:33:17  90.31
```

Where we match the first 539 stocks of AAPL bought with the first 200 being sold. Using First-in First-out accounting. Then continue with the remaining 447 being sold. Our first tier now has 539-200 = 339 stocks left. so we also sell those from the second 447 SELL. Leaving us with 447-339 = 108. Then we sell the next buy order of 8. And lastly, we sell the last 100. In this example, the sell price was the same for all of them. But this can be different!

I was considering using `cumsum` over `Quantity` to find the points where the cumulative sum of `Quantity` is 0. In between these points is when all previous positions are closed (because I have the data filtered in order of time). I am not sure where to go from here.

Once a solution is found for one ticker, I think it will be easy to use `data.table` to apply the solution to the entire table with other tickers using the `by` argument.

Comment: You don't really say what you want to do. Not everyone here is versed in stock trading lingo, so you might have better chances by explaining what exactly should be calculated.

Comment: Also generally better to restate the question here rather than link to a similar question (doubling the required reading and yet still probably falling short of clarity), I think.